# how to get the timestamps of a command execution in dockerfile

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile

This is normal way of doing in shell

```
starttime=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

#echo $starttime
# sleep for 5 seconds
sleep 5

# end time
endtime=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
#echo $endtime


STARTTIME=$(date -d "${starttime}" +%s)
ENDTIME=$(date -d "${endtime}" +%s)
RUNTIME=$((ENDTIME-STARTTIME))
echo "Seconds ${RUNTIME} in sec"
```

Wanted the same way in a docker file

Wanted to get the timestamps before and after execution of a command in dockerfile

Could some please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same.  A `RUN` command runs an ordinary Bourne shell command line (wrapping it in `sh -c`).  If you have this much scripting involved you might consider writing it into a shell script, `COPY`ing the script into your image, then `RUN`ning it.

If this is just for temporary diagnostics, and you don't *need* to calculate the time in seconds, you can just run `date` as is without the rest of the scripting.

```sh
RUN date; make; date # except this won't actually stop on failure
```

If you were especially motivated you could take the script from the question, make it take a command as an argument, and write a script around it

```sh
#!/bin/sh
starttime=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
sh -c "$@"
rc=$?
endtime=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
...
exit "$rc"
```

Then in your Dockerfile you can use the [`SHELL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell) directive to make this run `RUN` commands.  You will rarely see `RUN` commands using JSON arrays, and this will bypass your script.

```sh
# must be executable and have a correct #!/bin/sh line
COPY timeit.sh /usr/local/bin
SHELL ["/usr/local/bin/timeit.sh"]
RUN make
RUN ["/bin/echo", "this will not be timed"]
```